# Is it necessary to annotate the template specializations of an exported entity with export?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

… or is it enough to declare them at the module interface unit?

test.cpp:

```
module;

#include <iostream>

export module M;

export
template<typename>
class T
{
public:
  void foo() const
    { std::cout << "T" << std::endl; }
};

// export <-- NOT exported
template<>
class T<int>
{
public:
  void foo() const
    { std::cout << "T<int>" << std::endl; }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
import M;

int main()
{
  T<int> x; 
  x.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ rm -f gcm.cache/* && $(HOME)/gcc-master/bin/g++ -O3 -fmodules-ts test.cpp main.cpp -o foo && ./foo
T<int>

$ $(HOME)/gcc-master/bin/g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 11.0.0 20210128 (experimental)
```

Comment: The standard is saying [something nonsensical](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.expl.spec#7.sentence-1) here. I think the intent is to not require `export`, since a partial specialization does not require `export` ([\[temp.spec.partial.general\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.partial.general#7.sentence-2)).

Comment: @cpplearner I've seen you opened https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4479. I'll keep track of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exporting affects only name lookup and linkage.  Neither of those is relevant to any kind of template specialization or instantiation, so they never need exporting.